# what does means?:NoReverseMatch at /post_detail/12/

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

My first question, I just started to learn Python, but recently encountered a problem, maybe the problem will be very simple, but I spent three days and could not find a solution,

this is traceback，

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_detail/12/

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blogs']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/blogs/templates/blogs/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<post_id>\\d+)/']
   1 : <p>
   2 :     <a href="{% url 'blogs:index' %}">My blogs</a> -
   3 : 
   4 :     <a href="{% url 'blogs:all_post' %}">All Post</a>
   5 : </p>
   6 : 
   7 : {% block content %}
   8 : 
   9 : {% endblock content %}

Traceback:

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/blogs/views.py" in post_detail
  32.     return render(request, 'blogs/post_detail.html', context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/am/Documents/PycharmProjects/practice/19.1_Blog/11_bg/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /post_detail/12/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<post_id>\\d+)/']
```

**this is my urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    # home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # show all post
    url(r'^all_post/$', views.all_post, name='all_post'),

    # show post deatil
    url(r'^post_detail/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),

    # add new post
    url(r'^new_post/$', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # edit post
    url(r'^edit_post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BlogPost
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import PostForm


def index(request):
    """psot home page"""
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html')


def all_post(request):
    """show all post"""
    all_post = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'all_post': all_post}
    return render(request, 'blogs/all_post.html', context)


def post_detail(request, post_id):
    """show post detail"""
    p_id = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post_date = p_id.date_added
    post_title = p_id.title
    post_text = p_id.text
    # print(post)
    # all_post = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    # post_detail = post_title.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    # post_detail = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    # post_detail = post_title.text
    context = {'p_id': p_id, 'post_date': post_date, 'post_title': post_title, 'post_text': post_text}
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_detail.html', context)


def new_post(request):
    """add new post"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:all_post'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)


def edit_post(request, post_id):
    """edit post"""
    e_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)
    # title = edit_id.title
    # text = edit_id.text

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PostForm(instance=e_post)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=e_post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:post_detail', args=[post_id]))
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:post_detail', args=[post_id]))

        # context = {'edit_id': edit_id, 'title': title, 'text': text, 'form': form}
        context = {'e_post': e_post, 'post_id': post_id, 'form': form}
        # context = {'post_id': post_id, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

**edit_post.html**

```
{% extends 'blogs/base.html' %}
{% block content %}


  <p>Edit post:</p>

   <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post_id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**formss.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # class title:
    #     model = BlogPost
    #     title = ['text']
    #     labels = {'text': ''}
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        # title = ['text']
        fields = ['title', 'text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'blogs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Title:{{ p_id.title }}</p>
  <p>Edit post</p>
  <p><a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post_id %}">Edit post</a></p>

 <ul>
     <li>
         <p>Time:{{ p_id.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
         <p>Post:{{ p_id.text|linebreaks }}</p>
     </li>

 </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Now I want to implement a function for editing my blog post, but I tried it many times and I didn't find the problem at all.
I think the problem is in the edit_post url, but I can't find the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include `post_id` in the template context:

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):

    context = {'p_id': p_id, 'post_date': post_date, 'post_title': post_title, 'post_text': post_text}
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_detail.html', context)
```

Therefore the following url tag is not going to work.

```
<a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post_id %}">Edit post</a>
```

You could fix it by adding `post_id` to the context:

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    ...
    post_id = p_id.id    
    context = {'p_id': p_id, 'post_date': post_date, 'post_title': post_title, 'post_text': post_text, 'post_id': post_id}
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_detail.html', context)
```

However there's no need to include all of the fields individually. Just include the post in the template.

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, 'blogs/post_detail.html', context)
```

Note that I've changed the variable name from `p_id` to `post`, because it's a model instance, not an id.

Then in the template you can access the fields from `post`:

```
 <p>Title:{{ post.title }}</p>
 <p>Edit post</p>
 <p><a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">Edit post</a></p>

 <ul>
     <li>
         <p>Time:{{ post.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
         <p>Post:{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
     </li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: thank you very so much, Now the code is working ，I tried it, but I didn't expect it to be wrong here, but there was a small problem in my code. The context and return were not indented. I forgive my carelessness. Now it's OK. I can sleep in peace. Good night everyone！

Answer (score 0):

In post_detail view you are sending this context to template

```
context = {'p_id': p_id, 'post_date': post_date, 'post_title': post_title, 'post_text': post_text}
```

and then in post_detail.html you are trying to send variable called 'post_id' which doesn't exist to an URL:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post_id %}">Edit post</a></p>
```

add post_id to your context and that's should work

```
context = {'post_id': post_id, 'p_id': p_id, 'post_date': post_date, 'post_title': post_title, 'post_text': post_text}
```

Comment: thank you very so much, Now the code is working ， Good night everyone！ahah